# Set comprehension gives "unhashable type" (set of list) in Python

Tags: python, set, set-comprehension

I have the following list of tuples:

```
list_of_tuples = [('True', 100, 'Text1'),
                  ('False', 101, 'Text2'),
                  ('True', 102, 'Text3')]
```

I want to collect all second elements of each tuple into a set:

```
my_set = set()
my_set.add({tup[1] for tup in list_of_tuples})
```

But it throws the following error:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'
```

When I print out the respective elements in the iteration, it shows that the result of the set comprehension contains not the expected scalars but lists:

```
print {tup[1] for tup in list_of_tuples}

set([100, 101, 102])
```

Why does this happen? Why does this put the elements into a list first and put then the list into a set without any hint to list? How could I correct my solution?

Comment: You here add *sets* to *sets*...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The individual items that you put into a set can't be mutable, because if they changed, the effective hash would change and the ability to check for inclusion would break down.

The content of `set` can be changed over its lifetime.So this is illegal.

So just try to use this:

```
list_of_tuples = [('True', 100, 'Text1'),
                  ('False', 101, 'Text2'),
                  ('True', 102, 'Text3')]


my_set= { tup[1] for tup in list_of_tuples }
# set comprehensions with braces
print my_set
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You're defining an empty set, then trying to add another set inside it. Instead, just create the set directly:

```
my_set = {tup[1] for tup in list_of_tuples}
```

And the result of your print is just the way Python represents sets; it's not showing you that there is a list, it's showing you a set consisting of 100, 101 and 102.